# Can Bitwise Operation on NULL value crash the code in C++

Tags: c++, null, bitwise-operators, nullable, bit-shift

It seems that my program crashes on this line where im doing some bitwise operation on "a" array filled with NULL values (empty array), can this be a cause to program crash?

```
const unsigned char a [ something ];
int b;
b = (a[0] & 0x0f) << 8;
```

Comment: A char is never NULL. A character array can have a 0 at the end to terminate a string, but even that is a valid char value.

Comment: Your program will probably not even compile, because a const value needs to be initialized. Please show your actual code.

Comment: Your program contains undefined behavior. If the program is crashing on this particular line, it doesn't mean that the problem is on that line. Try to isolate the issue, and provide [mcve].

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code below

```
const unsigned char a [ something ];
int b;
b = (a[0] & 0x0f) << 8;
```

*by itself* cannot cause your program to crash. Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: Though unlikely to cause a crash, `a` is not initialized, and `a[0]` is actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sry for lack of info, this char a is a given to the function as parameter, but this parameter is some "get...()" function called from nullpointer, so im guessing this is the cause to crash, the tool in which im analyzing the crash logs points to the line in my original post and that confused me... Thanks for answers guys

Comment: @Bodega Yes if a was a null pointer, that could easily cause a crash.